# How to get a tooltip to show when users hover over a div with a certain class and not show on others

Tags: html, css, tooltip

I've actually got the tooltip showing where I want it to show, that part is working. The text it's displaying is contained in a `<span>` that's hidden until they hover over a `div` that has the tooltip class on it, similar to [the example](https://www.w3schools.com/css/css_tooltip.asp) on w3schools.com.

I have a column of `div`'s and only certain ones get the tooltip class. The problem I'm having is that the span is successfully hidden in the `div`'s that *don't* have the tooltip class, but it's still reserving the space for it and I'm having trouble figuring out how to get it to not do that.

I'm hiding the `<span>` with `CSS`'s `visibilty:hidden` which hides the text but the space for it is still reserved. If I change it to `display:none` instead of `visibility:hidden` it hides the text and does not reserve the space for it, which makes sense and that is almost what I want except I can't make it visible again without posting back.

So now I'm debating putting the whole thing inside of an ajax call so I don't have to refresh the whole page, but I'm not sure that would work either.

Is this even possible, or does anyone have any suggestions?

I appreciate any help anyone can offer.

Thanks

Comment: I added display:none and then on hover display:block on w3school code example. It worked for me!

Comment: Maybe post your code, or add a snippet link?

Comment: it did? Okay maybe I have something else further up overriding my display:block, I'll double check and reply again

Comment: that did work and there was another line in my CSS overriding my display:block. If you post what you said as an answer I'll mark yours as correct since you said it first. Thanks for the help

Comment: No worries, I will post it. Thanks!

Comment: Actually, you can mark Hussnain's answer. It's cool with me :'D

Answer (score 0, accepted):

what you can do is, give that div an id, and through css hover, set the tooltip's display to block,

or you can use, javascript for this, regidter those divs with a on hover, function , check the target of the hovered element, if it matches with that one, set tooltip's div display property to block,,simple

Answer (score 1):

You can try span{position:absolute}

Use js instead of css.

If you use css then it'll also create problems on responsive.

You can use bootstrap tooltip or simple jQuery 
https://jqueryui.com/tooltip/